# Eclipse won't start after crash

Tags: eclipse, startup

I received an error about how Eclipse was caught in a loop and something about garbage collecting...after I finally got it closed, I tried reopening and it won't work.  I tried the following from the command line:

eclipse -clean

and it still doesn't work.  I posted the error log at
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EPwYgHujbD8fX-W-b1DatJutgNv-ZnIkm8SP180R4XQ/edit

This is a fresh error log (single attempt to open eclipse)

Anyone know about eclipse errors that can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just reinstalling eclipse...

Answer (score 5):

Delete the .metadata folder from the workspace or change the workspace folder.
To make the eclipse ask where should your workspace be follow the steps below.

Find the file org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs in your eclipse\configuration.settings folder.

Change SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=false to true.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar crash and starting eclipse with `-clean` option did not help. I ended up deleting the `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench` file, which fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your workspace becomes corrupted and Eclipse can't open that workspace.

Can you open/create another workspace?

Comment: I don't even get an option to select a workspace.  I get the splash screen for about a second and then it disappears.

Comment: Nope, even restarted the computer to be sure

Comment: Suggest that you rename your Eclipse folder and get a fresh install. Never seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an issue where Eclipse wouldn't start. The splash screen appeared for a second, but never showed the workspace select screen, just like the OP said. I was about to reinstall when I took one last look at my eclipse.ini file. I found that I had left the m off one of the memory allocation settings. This caused it to crash with no error messages. So, perhaps malformed ini files can cause this issue.